# Numpy array value error

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, python-3.x

This is my code to train a sigmoid neuron for Iris dataset .

```
convergence = np.Infinity
    
    temp_y_hat = np.zeros((80,1))
    alpha = 1
    epochs = 0
    
    
    for i in range(100):
        temp_y_hat = np.zeros((80,1))
        for i in range(X_train.shape[0]):
            
            print("W : ",W.shape)
            print("X_train :",X_train.iloc[[i]].shape)
                       
            #res = np.dot(W,np.reshape(X_train.iloc[i].values,(-1,1))) + b
            res =np.dot(W,X_train.iloc[[i]].T) + b
            
            z = 1/(1 + np.exp(-res))
            
            if z >= 0.5:
                temp_y_hat[i] = 1
            elif z < 0.5:
                temp_y_hat[1] = 0
        
            if y_train[i]==temp_y_hat[i]:
                continue
            else:
                if y_train[i]==1 and temp_y_hat[i]==0:
                    #W = W + alpha*(np.reshape(X_train.iloc[i].values,(1,4)))
                    W = W + alpha*X_train.iloc[[i]]
                    b = b + alpha
                elif y_train[i]==0 and temp_y_hat[i]==1:
                    #W = W - alpha*(np.reshape(X_train.iloc[i].values,(1,4)))
                    W = W - alpha*X_train.iloc[[i]]
                    b = b - alpha
        
        
        convergence =  np.sum(np.square(np.subtract(y_train,temp_y_hat)))
        
        print("convergence ",convergence)
        epochs = epochs + 1
        
    print("epochs ",epochs)
    
                    
        
    return W , b
```

When I run this code , I am getting the following error :

```
if z >= 0.5:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

When I print out the shape of W and X_train.iloc[[i]] in each iteration :
I get the following output which is fine in the first 4 iterations whereas in the 5th iteration , the shape of matrix W becomes wrong and hence I get the above error .

```
1st iteration : W :  (1, 4)
X_train : (1, 4)
2nd iteration : W :  (1, 4)
X_train : (1, 4)
3rd iteration : W :  (1, 4)
X_train : (1, 4)
4th iteration : W :  (1, 4)
X_train : (1, 4)
5th iteration : W :  (2, 4)  --- wrong shape 
X_train : (1, 4)
```

I am suspecting the problem is in the segment where I'm updating the value of W .

```
 if y_train[i]==1 and temp_y_hat[i]==0:
                    #Commented W = W + alpha*(np.reshape(X_train.iloc[i].values,(1,4)))
                    W = W + alpha*X_train.iloc[[i]]
                    b = b + alpha
                elif y_train[i]==0 and temp_y_hat[i]==1:
                    # Commented W = W - alpha*(np.reshape(X_train.iloc[i].values,(1,4)))
                    W = W - alpha*X_train.iloc[[i]]
                    b = b - alpha
```

But , given that , W is (1,4) and X_train.iloc[[i]] is also(1,4) , and that I take transpose of X_train.iloc[[i]] in np.dot , Why am I getting this error ??

Can someone please help me understand the problem and get rid of this problem ?

Comment: dump numpy. use pytorch.

Comment: So this error won't go away?

Comment: Hi. no need to switch to pytorch, don't worry. What about this line : `temp_y_hat[1] = 0`, shouldn't it be `temp_y_hat[i] = 0` ? This could cause the error

Comment: thanks for pointing it out . Rectified it but still it doesn't help with the error .

Comment: How is b initialized ?

Comment: I initialized b = 0 in the main function and passed it to this function for training

Comment: Well, If I were you I'd add many `print(...)` to see the shapes and type of each object, at each computation step...

Comment: @Bharathi , I am not saying that. I am just providing you with a suggestion. I have found PyTorch to be much more convenient for calculations related to tensors. It is very well-designed and nicely optimized.